# laravel pusher - send event on production not working

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

this is the first time Im using pusher (pusher.com),all fine on local but on production sending notification not working, if I sent from local it works and send notification to production but send from live it is not working!!!

broadcasting:

```
       'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
        'cluster'=> env('CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        
        ],
    ],
```

sending function:

```
 public function OrderEvent()
{
   

$order_number='150';

    event(new OrderSubmitted($order_number));
   return "We just sent!";
}
```

error in production:

```
 production.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\OrderSubmitted] on channels [order-submitted] with payload:
 {
 "order_number": "15-EA",
 "socket": null
 }
```

Comment: That's not an error, though.

Comment: so why in production it is not sending!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 3):

It was because my broadcast_driver was set to `log` in the .env file.
Change the broadcast driver in your `.env` from `log` to `pusher`

`BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

And then, run this command on your production server.

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thanks man, I've been pulling my hair for days because of this issue and I just realise I did not change the driver in my .env in production (face palm)

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that you were able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This **usually** happends if you haven't verified your email at pusher.

If you arleady have done that, make sure you got this in your config file. (*broadcasitng.php*)

```
      'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap2',
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
```

---

If none of above works, it's most likely your hostname that's misconfigured.
Remember to exclude `http/https` from the host. It's not `https://example.com`, it's `example.com`

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST'),
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME')
    ],
],
```

and the `.env` file with:

```
PUSHER_HOST=example.com
```